# Is this database scheme sensible?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I need some help designing my database for a PHP website about furniture.

I have many main typologies, that is the application field. For example, office, outdoor, etc.

I have categories such as leather, cloth, etc.

A category can have multiple typologies. For example, a cloth item can be used in an office and outdoor and, for example, leather can’t be used in an office.

Each category has a field named “link” to store an image to be shown in the menu of the PHP page.

A page also has a Language field to display descriptions in different languages.

Each category has many products inside. Some categories have the same product as other categories inside.

For example,

- leather can be used in an office to make a leather chair.
- A cloth item can be used in an office to make a cloth sofa.
- But a leather item can be used outdoor to make a leather chair too.

So the same product can be in two categories.

A product has many model images (rear view, front view, color red, color black, etc.).

Some products have a kind of technical chart, while other products have another kind of technical chart. For example, for a cloth chair I don’t want to show the width, while for a leather chair I want to show whether or not it is breakable. The technical charts have different languages too.

This is my first big database.

Is the scheme below okay? Or do I have a concept flaw?

[image: Schematic diagram]

(I add an administrator so it is possible to add or cancel a product or category.)

To clarify, I have more or less this:

- **typology:** office, outdoor, automotive, marine, contract, leisure
- **category:** leather, simil-leather, cloth, tyvek
- **product:** chair, sofa, umbrella, table, cover, ...

Every product can belong just to one category but can be used for more than a typology. So, for example, a chair can be made *just* of leather, but can be used for more than one typology.

When I choose a typology on my website I want to show the categories in that typology (categories can be shared between typologies), then I want to choose a product in that category and see which typology can be used in.

Here is an updated database scheme:

[image: Schematic diagram]

Comment: is it the pages or the products that need descriptions in different languages?

Comment: Technical chart need to be done in different Language. And for
category brief description have to be done in different Language and for different typology. (e.g. if i am in typology office, i want to write, my leather is resistant to ink, while if i am in outdoor i want to write my leather is resistant to UV.

Comment: IMO: The relationship between typology and category is implicit, not explicit as you described. Your product table should have a category and a typology. The relationship between the category and typology is based on a product having both. Otherwise with your design, you can have a cloth sofa (i.e., category = cloth). It has implied typologies of office and outdoor.

Comment: but i can't link a product to a typology passing trought category?

Comment: @AgRizzo sorry, my bad, you are right, i got influenced by website design, because each typology has different category inside.

I mean: If i choose outdoor->I should see just the category that belong to outdoor
If i choose office -> i should see the category belonging to office (some of them can be the shared) 
AND each product can be used in more than one typology

Answer (score 0):

First rule, prevent a category from being entered twice or more times in a database.  For example entering the photo and description of the leather that can be used indoors AND outdoors OR both.  Let's say you have a table for 'material'.  Whatever material you have for your furniture, I would categorize as follows for example:  Type {Enum('indoor', 'outdoor', 'in-outdoor')} OR in numberic format i.e. {'1','2','3'} where you can put a note in your Comments section, inside the table what the numbers stand for.

Then call the material from your materials table instead of creating indoor material table and outdoor material table separately.

Comment: i have just 1 table for typology, in relation N:M with category, so i don't reenter it. the problem is that typology are 7 (if i watch image it's clearer xD)

Comment: What does the number 7 stand for?  Do you mean you have 7 different variables inside the table?

Comment: yeah typology are 7 kind of different typology (application field of the product)

Comment: What I am saying is that 'office' and 'outdoor' are one category.  Meaning, they define WHERE it can be used.  No need to put a variable called 'office' and a variable called 'outdoor'.

Comment: Perhaps it will help if you tell me what your variables are. I think you will need more than two tables, such as 'image' table linked to 'language' table.

Comment: typology:[office, furniture, outdoor, automotive] 
category:[leather, simil-leather, cloth, tyvek]
product:[chair, sofa, umbrella, table, cover, ...]

for example, chair can be made JUST of leather and can be used for more than a typology.

Comment: Typology: office, outdoor, automotive (not furniture!).

Comment: yes sorry, it's just to make an example acually are:
office, outdoor, automotive, marine, contract, leisure

Any way i just need to validate relationship :( PS (See my edit)

Comment: Sorry, I was brainstorming and can't delete my previous comment.

Comment: Think this way.  WHAT is  your product?  WHERE to use it?  WHAT kind of material? These are all separate categories and therefore, separate tables.  Then you link them by giving each table an ID number.  Then you call them according to office, furniture, English, for example.  Or you call them Marine, furniture, German, etc.  So you need more tables.

Comment: Contract is another category that would require:  Contract to a buyer?  Contract to supplier? and so on.  So you need a Contacts table that would include different kind of contacts, such as buyer, supplier, employees, etc.  They again will need their own tables, such as contact info, when you hired, sold... it just branches out and you grab to the data that you need in your various screens.

Comment: i can't keep in the same table with a column to indicate Language then extract with a select when i need Language change?
no contract is a typology, my db is very simple, contract is like outdoor, means can be used in hotel

Comment: Language table is separate. 'Outdoor' sounds like garden furniture. You can call it 'hospitality' or 'premium'.  Again, you will need more than just two tables.  Even if simple.

Comment: If you have 3 different materials for a chair: Leather -- Simil-leather -- Cloth.  You will need a table for each material's color, for example. Then you create 'Leather' table, 'Simil' table and 'Cloth' table where you can call out in what colors they come.  If you decide to put all in one table, you will end up with too many categories.  If your PHP is not enough developed, you may want to opt your ways for now, but I would not recommend such setup for the long run.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't bad for a first try. (BTW I used to work for a major furniture company, so this is a rare case where I actually know something about the real-world data that a question that I'm trying to answer on Stackoverflow is referring to!)

The biggest issue I see is the relationship between Typology and Category. By linking the product to Typology through Category, this means that what seem to me to be the same Category, e.g. "leather", would require multiple records, one for each possible Typology. For example if you have leather office furniture and also leather living room furniture, you would have to create two leather records.

I think it would make more sense to have an FK from Product to Category and a separate, unrelated FK from Product to Typology. I'd guess you don't need to enforce restrictions that, say, office furniture cannot be wicker. You just won't have any such Product records. But if you do need to enforce this, then I'd add another table in the database that connects Category and Typology and that would encode all possible combinations. That is, there could be a Category-Typology records for (office, leather), (living room, leather), (office, fabric), (outdoor, wicker), etc. Then before adding a Product record you verify that the combination is legal, either in application code or in a trigger.

I have mixed feelings about linking the technical charts to the Product through Chart_type. What did this extra table gain you? Why not just link them directly to the Product record? I take it you can only have one or the other chart types, not both? But creating the intermediate table doesn't prevent the creation of both records. I think you need code (or a trigger) to say that if one exists, you don't allow creation of the other or give a warning. When you're looking for one, just left join on both tables and see which you find. If you need to specify which is required for a given Product before the tech spec record is created, then put a field in Product to say which is required. If which is needed is not determined until you actually create one, then the existence of the record says which is needed and you don't need any additional field.

I'm not clear what Category_type is for. Assuming you need to link Categories to Typologies, why not just link them directly? Why the table in the middle?

And just by the way, some of your terminology seems very odd. Is this terminology dictated by the client, or are you trying to translate from another language?

Because by "category" you seem to mean "material". Why not call it by the much more specific and clear "material"?

By "model" you appear to mean "image" or "picture". Why not call it that? "Model" is a synonym for "product". (Some companies will use them to mean different things, usually that a model is a subtype of a given product or vice versa.)

The word "typology" means "a system for assigning types", not a type. You could call this table "Type". I generally don't like to call things "type" because that is very vague: when we ask what "type: a piece of furniture is do we expect someone to reply "bedroom", "leather", "colonial", "top quality", "imported", or any of dozens of other possible categorizations? Personally I'd call this table "setting".

But if you're translating, maybe the original names make perfect sense and this is a moot point.

Comment: I got your point in separating that 2 table.
I put a table in the mid because is a N:M relationship, so i need to pass thought a mid table. (typology is related to category) Because on my site when i choose a typology, i need to show all the category for a typology.

Actually, product is unique. I mean i can't have 1 product for 2 category.

Also, the Language is ok to put in the table like that? So i have multiple record of the same item in different Language, everyone with a EN or IT or FR near them. So i can take exctract whatever i want.

Comment: I don't see where you have the M:M. Maybe I'm just missing it or maybe you have the cardinalities backwards somewhere.

Comment: i mean, since a product can have multiple field of us, and a field of use can have multiple product, it's a N:M relationship. So i need to pass through a table

Comment: the only problem is that to recover which material has an application field i have to do 4 join

Comment: But you have no M:M's in your diagram. Anyway, in your diagram as is, you show a Category linking to multiply Typologies, but there's no way to tell which Typology applies to a given Product. That is, if you say that, e.g., you can have Leather for Office and for Living Room, and you say that Leather Sofa Style XYZ is in Category Leather, how do you know whether it's Office or Living Room? That's why I say you need a link from Product to Category and a link from Product to Typology. You can't link through Category. It doesn't work.

Comment: Thank you i got it now, I have now M:M category to typology and a separate M:M from typology to product i will then, when inserting a product, limit the insertion by category. So a product of a category can't have a typology that that product category doesn't have.